# how to fetch data from the database in angular 7?

Tags: php, angular, fetch, angular7

I am having while fetching data from the database using PHP fetch API.
below PHP fetch API working fine with the react App but giving error using fetching using angular.
here is my complete code with PHP fetch API.

`app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}
  name = 'My App';
 students:any = [];
  baseUrl='http://veomit.com/test/zend/api/fetch.php';
  get_products(){
        this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl).subscribe((res :{})=>{
        console.log(res);
        this.students = res;
        });
    }
}
```

`app.component.html`:

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<button (click)="get_products()">GET Data</button>
<ul>
      <li *ngFor="let student of students" >
        userId: {{student.name}}
        Hellotitle: {{student.department}}
        body: {{student.marks}}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

php fetch API - fetch.php

````
<?php 

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Request-Headers: GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT");
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql1004.mochahost.com","a310387_task_for","task_force","a310387_task_force");
$ar=array();

     $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from student");
     while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $ar[]=$rows;
     }
 echo json_encode($ar);

 ?>
```
Below is my console error:

    HttpErrorResponse {headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://veomit.com/test/zend/api/fetch.php"…}
    error: ProgressEvent
    isTrusted: true
    __proto__: ProgressEvent
    headers: HttpHeaders
    headers: Array[0]
    lazyUpdate: null
    normalizedNames: Array[0]
    __proto__: HttpHeaders
    message: "Http failure response for http://veomit.com/test/zend/api/fetch.php: 0 Unknown Error"
    name: "HttpErrorResponse"
    ok: false
    status: 0
    statusText: "Unknown Error"
    url: "http://veomit.com/test/zend/api/fetch.php"
    __proto__: HttpErrorResponse
````

Comment: Minor text format

Answer (score -1):

plz first generate services from this command 
ng g service service_name
then constuct a function --

```js
 getAllData(url, headerData = {}){
    const getUrl = this.apiUrl + url;
    //let header:any={'authtoken':this.token};
    return this.http.get(getUrl, { headers: headerData })
    .map(result => result)
    .catch(this.handleError)
  }
```

then in app componen.ts

```js
get_product(){

 this.service_name.getAllData(this.url).subscribe(
   (response: any) => {

      if (response.status == true) {
      
      } else {
       
      }
    });
}
```